Invalid or corrupted pad block using encrypt package
I am using encrypt package from a while time to decrypt messages from server that I encrypted before everything was working fine but when I clean my packages from pubspec.yaml file this error appear that says:

Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block

It's confusing, I don't think the problem was from cleaning packages at all.
my code:

import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;

class EncryptMessages{

  static encryptWithAESKey(String data) {
    encrypt.Key aesKey = encrypt.Key.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(aesKey));
    encrypt.Encrypted encryptedData =
    encrypter.encrypt(data, iv: encrypt.IV.fromLength(16)); ///allZerosOfLength
    return encryptedData.base64;
  }

  static decryptWithAESKey(String data) {
    encrypt.Key aesKey = encrypt.Key.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(aesKey));
    encrypt.Encrypted encrypted = encrypt.Encrypted.fromBase64(data);
    String decryptedData =
    encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: encrypt.IV.fromLength(16)); ///allZerosOfLength
    return decryptedData;
  }
}


using encrypt: ^5.0.3
I tried to change package version to ^5.0.1, ^5.0.2
I tried allZerosOfLength
I tried padding to "PKCS7"

At least in newer encrypt versions, Key.fromLength() and IV.fromLength() return a random byte sequence for key and IV, so your data is probably inconsistent. Log the data during encryption and decryption and check its consistency.

Check also flutter encrypt package multi platform unencryption and #issue 314.

I was also facing the same error
Cause: IV value is not constant, new value is generated in each runtime.
To decrypt the data We need to use the same IV that we use to encrypt it.
Solution:

generate IV
Store the base64 of IV to secure storage just like key

Code
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorage {
  SecureStorage._();

  static final SecureStorage _instance = SecureStorage._();

  factory SecureStorage() {
    return _instance;
  }

  final _storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  late encrypt.Key encryptionKey;
  late encrypt.IV iv;

  Future<void> init() async {
    await _getKey();
    await _getIV();
  }

  Future<void> _getKey() async {
    String? key = await _storage.read(key: 'encryptionKey');
    if (key == null) {
      key = encrypt.Key.fromLength(32).base64; // Create a new key if not exists
      await _storage.write(key: 'encryptionKey', value: key);
    }
    encryptionKey = encrypt.Key.fromBase64(key);
  }

  Future<void> _getIV() async {
    String? iv64 = await _storage.read(key: 'encryptionIV');
    if (iv64 == null) {
      iv64 = encrypt.IV.fromLength(16).base64; // Create a new IV if not exists
      await _storage.write(key: 'encryptionIV', value: iv64);
    }
    iv = encrypt.IV.fromBase64(iv64);
  }

  String encryptData(String data) {
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(encryptionKey));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(data, iv: iv);
    return encrypted.base64;
  }

  String decryptData(String encryptedData) {
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(encryptionKey));
    return encrypter.decrypt64(encryptedData, iv: iv);
  }
}


